# Filtering items by relation using knex query

Tags: sql, knex.js, strapi, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to filter items by relation using a knex query. I'm almost there (I think) but struggling a little and could use some help as this is new to me.

I have a list of users who are following people and have followers. I'm trying to return a list of users who I'm not already following. Below is my code so far:

```
const users = await knex("users-permissions_user").whereNotExists(
  function () {
    this.select("*")
      .from("users_followers__users_followings")
      .where("user_id", "users-permissions_user.id")
      .where("follower_id", id);
  }
);
```

This returns a list of users who currently have no followers and users where I'm the only follower. Any users who I follow and also have more followers are still returned. I thought `like` would achieve this type of filter but I must be doing it wrong.

Here is how the table for the followers/following relation appears in my db:
[image]

And here is the data that would be returned from the above query:

```
[
  {
    "id": "138",
    "followers": [
      {
        "id": "143"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "140",
    "followers": [
      {
        "id": "160"
      },
      {
        "id": "136"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "135",
    "followers": []
  },
  {
    "id": "136",
    "followers": []
  }
]
```

As you can see, users with no followers are returned as are users who I'm not already following but users who have multiple followers, including me (ID `160`), are returned when they should be omitted.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason that users like `140` are being returned even though they are following you (`160`) is because they are following at least one other person who isn't you, which means your `where` clause will match them.
If you want to return only users who are not following you, you could achieve this by replacing your `left join` and `where` clause with a `where not exists` clause. In knex that would look something like:

```js
qb.whereNotExists(function() {
     this.select(1)
    .from('users_followers__users_followings')
    .where('users_followers__users_followings.user_id', knex.ref('users-permissions_user.id'))
    .where('users_followers__users_followings.follower_id', id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have tried this but now it's simply returning all users and not filtering at all 

Comment: Hmm, are you able to supply the full query you are running? That might shed some more light on the issue

Comment: I updated my code snippet above to show the full query

Comment: Aah sorry I think I see the mistake. So in the `where` clause, the 2nd argument is being taken as the literal string `'users-permissions_user.id'` rather than a reference to that column. Adding `knex.ref` should hopefully fix this. I've updated the snippet in my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a million : )